# How do you toggle menu button for simple sidebar bootstrap 3 w/Meteor using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a menu button, for my off canvas sidebar. I'm using the cannonstar:sidebar-bootstrap3 (AKA start bootstrap simple sidebar). http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/
http://seegatesite.com/bootstrap/simple_sidebar_menu.html#

My problem is that it isn't working can anyone who willing to help me, look at my code please; thanks to all that help.

P.S. I'm using Meteor & Boostrap-3 with the iron-router package.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="{{pathFor'home'}}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{pathFor'home'}}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{pathFor'about'}}">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{pathFor'contact'}}">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" id="menu-toggle">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar brand" href="#"></a>
                    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle-2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="{{pathFor'home'}}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{pathFor'about'}}">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{pathFor'contact'}}">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">{{> loginButtons}}</a></li> 
        </ul>
                    </div>

                </nav>

    <header class="masthead">
        <div class="container">
            <h1><a href="#" title=""></a></h1>
        </div>
    </header>


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
    $("#menu-toggle-2").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled-2");
});
```

Comment: Have you checked console for error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are declared different in Meteor:

Assuming template name: `<template name="honeybadger">..</template>`

```
Template.honeybadger.events({
  'click #menu-toggle': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
  }
}
```

Further Reading: [Meteor documentation about Template events](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Template-events)