# sidebar in bootstrap3 not working in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Here is the html code I used:

```
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    Start Bootstrap
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Overview</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

           <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                    <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                    <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```

I copied the above code from [simple sidebar bootstrap example](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/)

Here is the output for meteor list command:

```
$ meteor list
accounts-facebook  1.0.4  Login service for Facebook accounts
accounts-ui        1.1.5  Simple templates to add login widgets to an app
autopublish        1.0.3  Publish the entire database to all clients
insecure           1.0.3  Allow all database writes by default
meteor-platform    1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
twbs:bootstrap     3.3.5  The most popular front-end framework for developing...
```

Does anyone know why bootstrap's sidebar doesn't work in Meteor please?

The [navbar example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/) did work though.

Comment: Are you loading jQuery in your package list? And this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839734/how-do-you-toggle-menu-button-for-simple-sidebar-bootstrap-3-w-meteor-using-jque

Comment: Yep. Just added jquery via: meteor add jquery.Still not seeing [sidebar][https://plus.google.com/+AlanTangh/posts/TxCfNUhXbFh?pid=6195706349643845650&oid=101820457203726161931].

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add CSS for it to display correctly and a jQuery function to toggle the Sidebar on and off screen. See working example.

```js
 $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
 });
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand"> <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Dashboard</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Overview</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Events</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">About</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Services</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Contact</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>

          <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the
            page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
          <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p> <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```